Spack Installation of Quantum-espresso (QE) not enabled to read data from a SCF calculation for input to a NSCF calculation
 We are requesting help for a stack installation of quantum espresso (QE) that is not reading all the data it needs from a self-consistent-field (SCF) calculation to perform a non-self-consistent field (NSCF) calculation.  We are not reporting this as a ‘bug’’ . Rather it is a problem we are encountering as we transition from desktop workstation QE to a High-Performance-Computing (HPC) Cluster with Spack software installations.  In order to clarify the problem, we present a simple exemplary calculation for NiO crystalline material referenced [here](http://amulet-code.org/images/amulet/exchanges_tutorial.pdf). We first describe the calculation and conclusions and put all the input and output data in Tables (Table 1A to 6A) in an APPENDIX at the end of this description.

First the SCF calculation is performed on an input data set, named pwscf.in.  After the calculation is completed the pw.x command directory has the following appearance,
      NiO.save   pwscf.in  pwscf.out                         (1)                                                                                      

Subsequently one would perform the NSCF calculation in the same directory and following the NSCF calculation the directory would have the following appearance
     NiO.save   npwscf.in  npwscf.out  pwscf.in  pwscf.out   (2)                              

To perform this NSCF calculation, the NSCF program would use data contained in NiO.save which is one of the output directories of the SCF program.  See Tables 1A and 2A of APPENDIX for a listing of data in pwscf.in and npwscf.in, respectively.   The expected result is that obtained in npwscf.out using the traditional ‘sudo apt’ QE installation and a subsequent ‘configure’ and ‘make’ compilation (See Table 3A of APPENDIX for a listing of this output).   This result is the Hamiltonian for the calculation in the form of eigenvalues and atomic densities.
    Here is where the difficulty with the Spack installation occurs.  The Spack installed QE fails to perform the data transfer from NiO.save because of an error described below.  

Atomic positions and unit cell read from directory:
./NiO.save/
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine qes_read: matrixType (10):                        (3)
     required attribute rank not found, can't read further, stopping
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

The complete output message in npwscf.out that includes the number of nodes(=1) and numbers of threads used (=16) is in Table 4A of the APPENDIX.
    All  output from the initial pwscf.in calculation using the spack installed QE appears to be to be the same as that obtained with the traditional ‘sudo apt’ and subsequent ‘make’ compilation.  The spack installation of QE was on a high performance HPC cluster with 1000 AMD nodes using the spack command given below.

    $ spack install quantum-espresso+openmp+scalapack +mpi hdf5=parallel
    %aocc ^amdfftw ^amdscalapack ^amdblis threads=openmp ^amdlibflame       (4)
    ^openmpi

The calculations in Table 3A using the traditional QE installation were performed on a HP Envy desktop computer (Windows 11 with Ubuntu linux option).
Since the error which stopped the npwscf.in computation occurred with the reading of data from the directory, NiO.save, we turn our attention to the truncated version of the file listings in that directory in the Table 1 below.
Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF  wfcdw3.hdf5   wfcdw54.hdf5  wfcup2.hdf5   wfcup44.hdf5
O.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF   wfcdw30.hdf5  wfcdw55.hdf5  wfcup20.hdf5  wfcup45.hdf5
charge-density.hdf5         wfcdw31.hdf5  wfcdw56.hdf5  wfcup21.hdf5  wfcup46.hdf5
data-file-schema.xml        wfcdw32.hdf5  wfcdw57.hdf5  wfcup22.hdf5  wfcup47.hdf5
occup.txt                   wfcdw33.hdf5  wfcdw58.hdf5  wfcup23.hdf5  wfcup48.hdf5
wfcdw1.hdf5                 wfcdw34.hdf5  wfcdw59.hdf5  wfcup24.hdf5  wfcup49.hdf5
wfcdw10.hdf5                wfcdw35.hdf5  wfcdw6.hdf5   wfcup25.hdf5  wfcup5.hdf5
wfcdw11.hdf5                wfcdw36.hdf5  wfcdw60.hdf5  wfcup26.hdf5  wfcup50.hdf5

Table 1. Truncated version of the listings in NiO.save in which the Wannier functions listings (wfcdw..hdf5) were deleted.  For a complete listing see Table 5A of APPENDIX
Table 1  data includes pseudo potentials, charge density, and xml data. We give a complete listing of this data in Table 5A of the APPENDIX.  The error described in npwscf.out (Table 4A) states the input is matrixType (10) and cannot be read, because the rank of the matrix is not specified.
We do not know why this problem occurs.  But we believe that ‘qes’ in  qes-read is an abbreviation for quantum-espresso and is referring to the file  named data-file-schema.xml (See Table 1 above). We have listed this file in Table 6A of the APPENDIX.  If that is the case interpreting this file as a matrix is the source of the problem.   This file should be read line by line until the end command which is labeled <qes_espress> rather than as a matrix with a well-defined rank.
We are asking for help to solve this problem.  We would like for the read error to be fixed because this would be simplest fix.  However at the same time we are open to advice that would require reinstallation of QE or  reprogramming the SCF to NSCF sequence.
In general, the technique of using SCF to NSCF to obtain a band structure with a fine k-point grid is a much-used technique by all researchers studying band structure of magnetic materials.  Although we did not see that in the list of similar questions, we are also hoping that we can benefit from the experience of other researchers in this field.
Begin APPENDIX
Table 1A.  pwscf.in for NiO.
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  max_seconds = 3.6000e+04
  prefix = 'NiO'
  pseudo_dir = './pseudo/'
/
&SYSTEM
  celldm(1) = 7.8828134
  degauss =   5.0000000000d-02
  ecutrho =   3.6000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   4.5000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 4
  ntyp = 3
  occupations = 'smearing'
  nspin=2
  starting_magnetization(1) = 0.5
  starting_magnetization(2) = -0.5
/
&ELECTRONS
conv_thr  =  1.00000e-07
/
CELL_PARAMETERS alat
0.50 0.50 1.00
0.50 1.00 0.50
1.00 0.50 0.50
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ni1     58.6934 Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
Ni2     58.6934 Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
O       15.9994 O.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS alat
Ni1          0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
Ni2          0.0000000000       0.0000000000       1.0000000000
O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000
O            1.5000000000       1.5000000000       1.5000000000
K_POINTS automatic
8 8 8 0 0 0
HUBBARD (ortho-atomic)
U Ni1-3d 7.1
U Ni2-3d 7.1

End of Table 1A.  pwscf.in for NiO.
Table 2A.   npwscf.in for NiO
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'nscf'
  max_seconds = 3.6000e+04
  prefix = 'NiO'
  pseudo_dir = './pseudo/'
/
&SYSTEM
  celldm(1) = 7.8828134
  degauss =   5.0000000000d-02
  ecutrho =   3.6000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   4.5000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nosym=.true.    noinv=.true.
  nat = 4
  ntyp = 3
  occupations = 'smearing'
  nspin=2
  starting_magnetization(1) = 0.5
  starting_magnetization(2) = -0.5
/
&ELECTRONS
conv_thr  =  1.00000e-07
/
CELL_PARAMETERS alat
0.50 0.50 1.00
0.50 1.00 0.50
1.00 0.50 0.50
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ni1     58.6934 Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
Ni2     58.6934 Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
O       15.9994 O.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS alat
Ni1          0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
Ni2          0.0000000000       0.0000000000       1.0000000000
O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000
O            1.5000000000       1.5000000000       1.5000000000
K_POINTS automatic
8 8 8 0 0 0
HUBBARD (ortho-atomic)
U Ni1-3d 7.1
U Ni2-3d 7.1

End of Table 2A.npwscf.in for NiO
Table 3A.  The Output, npwscf.out used sudo-apt install
with HPEnvy Intel i9 core laptop Computer.  This is
the result that is expected.
Serial multi-threaded version, running on   20 processor cores
31074 MiB available memory on the printing compute node when the environment starts
 Waiting for input...
 Reading input from standard input

 Current dimensions of program PWSCF are:
 Max number of different atomic species (ntypx) = 10
 Max number of k-points (npk) =  40000
 Max angular momentum in pseudopotentials (lmaxx) =  4
 Message from routine volume:
 axis vectors are left-handed

 Atomic positions and unit cell read from directory:
 ./NiO.save/

 Message from routine volume:
 axis vectors are left-handed
 file Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF: wavefunction(s)  3D renormalized
 file Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF: wavefunction(s)  3D renormalized

 G-vector sticks info
 --------------------
 sticks:   dense  smooth     PW     G-vecs:    dense   smooth      PW
 Sum        1475     737    245                28291    10017    1973

 Using Slab Decomposition



 bravais-lattice index     =            0
 lattice parameter (alat)  =       7.8828  a.u.
 unit-cell volume          =     244.9141 (a.u.)^3
 number of atoms/cell      =            4
 number of atomic types    =            3
 number of electrons       =        32.00
 number of Kohn-Sham states=           20
 kinetic-energy cutoff     =      45.0000  Ry
 charge density cutoff     =     360.0000  Ry

APPENDIX(Continued)
Table 3A.  The Output, npwscf.out (Continued)
Exchange-correlation= LDA
                           (   1   1   0   0   0   0   0)

 celldm(1)=   7.882813  celldm(2)=   0.000000  celldm(3)=   0.000000
 celldm(4)=   0.000000  celldm(5)=   0.000000  celldm(6)=   0.000000

 crystal axes: (cart. coord. in units of alat)
           a(1) = (   0.500000   0.500000   1.000000 )  
           a(2) = (   0.500000   1.000000   0.500000 )  
           a(3) = (   1.000000   0.500000   0.500000 )  

 reciprocal axes: (cart. coord. in units 2 pi/alat)
           b(1) = ( -0.500000 -0.500000  1.500000 )  
           b(2) = ( -0.500000  1.500000 -0.500000 )  
           b(3) = (  1.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000 )  


 PseudoPot. # 1 for Ni read from file:
 ./pseudo/Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
 MD5 check sum: 4def80e42349afdd14834ce81d852c61
 Pseudo is Ultrasoft + core correction, Zval = 10.0
 Generated using "atomic" code by A. Dal Corso  v.5.0.2 svn rev. 9415
 Using radial grid of 1195 points,  6 beta functions with: 
            l(1) =   0
            l(2) =   0
            l(3) =   1
            l(4) =   1
            l(5) =   2
            l(6) =   2
 Q(r) pseudized with 0 coefficients 


 PseudoPot. # 2 for Ni read from file:
 ./pseudo/Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
 MD5 check sum: 4def80e42349afdd14834ce81d852c61
 Pseudo is Ultrasoft + core correction, Zval = 10.0
 Generated using "atomic" code by A. Dal Corso  v.5.0.2 svn rev. 9415
 

APPENDIX(Continued)
Table 3A.  The Output, npwscf.out (Continued)
Using radial grid of 1195 points,  6 beta functions with:
            l(1) =   0
            l(2) =   0
            l(3) =   1
            l(4) =   1
            l(5) =   2
            l(6) =   2
 Q(r) pseudized with 0 coefficients 


 PseudoPot. # 3 for O  read from file:
 ./pseudo/O.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF
 MD5 check sum: 6e384d5705d3ad042f52b90450e69d34
 Pseudo is Ultrasoft + core correction, Zval =  6.0
 Generated using "atomic" code by A. Dal Corso  v.5.0.2 svn rev. 9415
 Using radial grid of 1095 points,  4 beta functions with: 
            l(1) =   0
            l(2) =   0
            l(3) =   1
            l(4) =   1
 Q(r) pseudized with 0 coefficients 


 atomic species   valence    mass     pseudopotential
    Ni1           10.00    58.69340     Ni( 1.00)
    Ni2           10.00    58.69340     Ni( 1.00)
    O              6.00    15.99940     O ( 1.00)

 Starting magnetic structure 
 atomic species   magnetization
    Ni1          0.500
    Ni2         -0.500
    O            0.000


 Simplified LDA+U calculation (l_max = 2) with parameters (eV):
 atomic species    L          U    alpha       J0     beta
    Ni1            2     7.1000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
    Ni2            2     7.1000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000

APPENDIX(Continued)
Table 3A.  The Output, npwscf.out (Continued)
  No symmetry found


   Cartesian axes

 site n.     atom                  positions (alat units)
     1           Ni1 tau(   1) = (   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  )
     2           Ni2 tau(   2) = (   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000  )
     3           O   tau(   3) = (   0.5000000   0.5000000   0.5000000  )
     4           O   tau(   4) = (   1.5000000   1.5000000   1.5000000  )

 number of k points=   512  Gaussian smearing, width (Ry)=  0.0500

 Number of k-points >= 100: set verbosity='high' to print them.

 Dense  grid:    28291 G-vectors     FFT dimensions: (  60,  60,  60)

 Smooth grid:    10017 G-vectors     FFT dimensions: (  45,  45,  45)

 Estimated max dynamical RAM per process >     114.80 MB

 Check: negative core charge=   -0.000040
 Generating pointlists ...
 new r_m :   0.2063 (alat units)  1.6258 (a.u.) for type    1
 new r_m :   0.2063 (alat units)  1.6258 (a.u.) for type    2
 new r_m :   0.2063 (alat units)  1.6258 (a.u.) for type    3

 The potential is recalculated from file :
 ./NiO.save/charge-density

 Number of +U iterations with fixed ns =  0
 Starting occupations:

 Hubbard parameters (eV):
 U(  1) =  7.1000
 U(  2) =  7.1000


 ================= HUBBARD OCCUPATIONS ================
 --------------------- ATOM    1 ----------------------
 Tr[ns] (up, down, total) =   4.97583  3.30300  8.27883
 Atomic magnetic moment =   1.67283
 SPIN  1
 eigenvalues:
   0.993  0.993  0.997  0.997  0.997
 eigenvectors (columns):
   0.365  0.931 -0.007  0.000 -0.000
   0.005  0.001  0.373 -0.726  0.577
  -0.003  0.004  0.442  0.686  0.577
   0.931 -0.365  0.000  0.007  0.000
   0.002  0.005  0.816 -0.040 -0.577
 occupation matrix ns (before diag.):
   0.993 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000
  -0.000  0.997  0.000 -0.000 -0.000
  -0.000  0.000  0.997  0.000 -0.000
  -0.000 -0.000  0.000  0.993 -0.000
  -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000  0.997
 SPIN  2
 eigenvalues:
   0.161  0.161  0.994  0.994  0.994
 eigenvectors (columns):
   0.413 -0.911 -0.001  0.000  0.000
  -0.001  0.000 -0.397  0.714  0.577
   0.000  0.001 -0.420 -0.700  0.577
   0.911  0.413  0.000  0.001  0.000
  -0.000  0.001 -0.816  0.013 -0.577
 occupation matrix ns (before diag.):
   0.161  0.000  0.000 -0.000  0.001
   0.000  0.994  0.000  0.001 -0.000
   0.000  0.000  0.994 -0.001 -0.000
  -0.000  0.001 -0.001  0.161 -0.000
   0.001 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000  0.994
 --------------------- ATOM    2 ----------------------
 Tr[ns] (up, down, total) =   3.30305  4.97584  8.27889
 Atomic magnetic moment =  -1.67278
 SPIN  1
 eigenvalues:
   0.161  0.161  0.994  0.994  0.994
 eigenvectors (columns):
   0.453 -0.892 -0.001  0.000  0.000
  -0.001  0.000 -0.338  0.743  0.577
   0.000  0.001 -0.474 -0.664  0.577
   0.892  0.453  0.000  0.001  0.000
  -0.000  0.001 -0.813  0.079 -0.577
 occupation matrix ns (before diag.):
   0.161  0.000  0.000 -0.000  0.001
   0.000  0.994  0.000  0.001 -0.000
   0.000  0.000  0.994 -0.001 -0.000
  -0.000  0.001 -0.001  0.161 -0.000
   0.001 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000  0.994
 SPIN  2
 eigenvalues:
   0.993  0.993  0.997  0.997  0.997
 eigenvectors (columns):
   0.402  0.916 -0.007  0.000 -0.000
   0.005  0.001  0.380 -0.722  0.577
  -0.003  0.004  0.435  0.691  0.577
   0.916 -0.402  0.000  0.007  0.000
   0.002  0.005  0.816 -0.032 -0.577
 occupation matrix ns (before diag.):
   0.993 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000
  -0.000  0.997  0.000 -0.000 -0.000
  -0.000  0.000  0.997  0.000 -0.000
  -0.000 -0.000  0.000  0.993 -0.000
  -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000  0.997

 Number of occupied Hubbard levels =   16.5577

Atomic wfc used for LDA+U Projector are orthogonalized
Starting wfcs are   26 randomized atomic wfcs
 Band Structure Calculation
 Davidson diagonalization with overlap

 ethr =  3.13E-10,  avg # of iterations = 31.2

 total cpu time spent up to now is     1533.8 secs

End of band structure calculation
 Number of k-points >= 100: set verbosity='high' to print the bands.

 the Fermi energy is    11.5299 ev
 (compare with:    11.5305 eV, computed in scf)

 Writing all to output data dir ./NiO.save/

=------------------------------------------------------------------------------=
JOB DONE. For npwscf.out
End of Table 3A.  The Output, npwscf.out used sudo-apt install
with HPEnvy Intel i9 core laptop Computer.  This is
the result that is expected.
Table 4A  The output obtained using spack installed QE on the HPC cluster
with 1000 AMD nodes.  Error failed to read routine-qes.  Program
Terminated.  This the result that is obtained
This program is part of the open-source Quantum ESPRESSO suite
 for quantum simulation of materials; please cite
     "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 21 395502 (2009);
     "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 29 465901 (2017);
     "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Chem. Phys. 152 154105 (2020);
      URL http://www.quantum-espresso.org", 
 in publications or presentations arising from this work. More details at
 http://www.quantum-espresso.org/quote

 Parallel version (MPI & OpenMP), running on      16 processor cores
 Number of MPI processes:                 1
 Threads/MPI process:                    16

 MPI processes distributed on     1 nodes
 312289 MiB available memory on the printing compute node when the environment starts

 Waiting for input...
 Reading input from standard input

 Current dimensions of program PWSCF are:
 Max number of different atomic species (ntypx) = 10
 Max number of k-points (npk) =  40000
 Max angular momentum in pseudopotentials (lmaxx) =  4
 file Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF: wavefunction(s)  3D renormalized
 file Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF: wavefunction(s)  3D renormalized
 Message from routine volume:
 axis vectors are left-handed

 Atomic positions and unit cell read from directory:
 ./NiO.save/



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine qes_read: matrixType (10):
     required attribute rank not found, can't read further, stopping
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     stopping ...

End of Table 4A  The output obtained using spack installed on a QE on a the HPC with 1000 AMD nodes.
Error failed to read routine-qes.  Program 
          Terminated.  **This is the result that is obtained**

Table 5A  Listing in Directory NiO.save
Ni.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF  wfcdw3.hdf5   wfcdw54.hdf5  wfcup2.hdf5   wfcup44.hdf5
O.pz-n-rrkjus_psl.0.1.UPF   wfcdw30.hdf5  wfcdw55.hdf5  wfcup20.hdf5  wfcup45.hdf5
charge-density.hdf5         wfcdw31.hdf5  wfcdw56.hdf5  wfcup21.hdf5  wfcup46.hdf5
data-file-schema.xml        wfcdw32.hdf5  wfcdw57.hdf5  wfcup22.hdf5  wfcup47.hdf5
occup.txt                   wfcdw33.hdf5  wfcdw58.hdf5  wfcup23.hdf5  wfcup48.hdf5
wfcdw1.hdf5                 wfcdw34.hdf5  wfcdw59.hdf5  wfcup24.hdf5  wfcup49.hdf5
wfcdw10.hdf5                wfcdw35.hdf5  wfcdw6.hdf5   wfcup25.hdf5  wfcup5.hdf5
wfcdw11.hdf5                wfcdw36.hdf5  wfcdw60.hdf5  wfcup26.hdf5  wfcup50.hdf5
wfcdw12.hdf5                wfcdw37.hdf5  wfcdw61.hdf5  wfcup27.hdf5  wfcup51.hdf5
wfcdw13.hdf5                wfcdw38.hdf5  wfcdw62.hdf5  wfcup28.hdf5  wfcup52.hdf5
wfcdw14.hdf5                wfcdw39.hdf5  wfcdw63.hdf5  wfcup29.hdf5  wfcup53.hdf5
wfcdw15.hdf5                wfcdw4.hdf5   wfcdw64.hdf5  wfcup3.hdf5   wfcup54.hdf5
wfcdw16.hdf5                wfcdw40.hdf5  wfcdw65.hdf5  wfcup30.hdf5  wfcup55.hdf5
wfcdw17.hdf5                wfcdw41.hdf5  wfcdw7.hdf5   wfcup31.hdf5  wfcup56.hdf5
wfcdw18.hdf5                wfcdw42.hdf5  wfcdw8.hdf5   wfcup32.hdf5  wfcup57.hdf5
wfcdw19.hdf5                wfcdw43.hdf5  wfcdw9.hdf5   wfcup33.hdf5  wfcup58.hdf5
wfcdw2.hdf5                 wfcdw44.hdf5  wfcup1.hdf5   wfcup34.hdf5  wfcup59.hdf5
wfcdw20.hdf5                wfcdw45.hdf5  wfcup10.hdf5  wfcup35.hdf5  wfcup6.hdf5
wfcdw21.hdf5                wfcdw46.hdf5  wfcup11.hdf5  wfcup36.hdf5  wfcup60.hdf5
wfcdw22.hdf5                wfcdw47.hdf5  wfcup12.hdf5  wfcup37.hdf5  wfcup61.hdf5
wfcdw23.hdf5                wfcdw48.hdf5  wfcup13.hdf5  wfcup38.hdf5  wfcup62.hdf5
wfcdw24.hdf5                wfcdw49.hdf5  wfcup14.hdf5  wfcup39.hdf5  wfcup63.hdf5
wfcdw25.hdf5                wfcdw5.hdf5   wfcup15.hdf5  wfcup4.hdf5   wfcup64.hdf5
wfcdw26.hdf5                wfcdw50.hdf5  wfcup16.hdf5  wfcup40.hdf5  wfcup65.hdf5
wfcdw27.hdf5                wfcdw51.hdf5  wfcup17.hdf5  wfcup41.hdf5  wfcup7.hdf5
wfcdw28.hdf5                wfcdw52.hdf5  wfcup18.hdf5  wfcup42.hdf5  wfcup8.hdf5
wfcdw29.hdf5                wfcdw53.hdf5  wfcup19.hdf5  wfcup43.hdf5  wfcup9.hdf5

End of Table 5A  Listing in Directory NiO.save
Table 6A Partial Listing of data-file-schema.xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<qes:espresso xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:qes="http://www.quantum-espresso.org/ns/qes/qes-1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quantum-espresso.org/ns/qes/qes-1.0 http://www.quantum-espresso.org/ns/qes/qes_230310.xsd" Units="Hartree atomic units">
<!-- All quantities are in Hartree atomic units unless otherwise specified -->
  <general_info>
    <xml_format NAME="QEXSD" VERSION="23.03.10">QEXSD_23.03.10</xml_format>
    <creator NAME="PWSCF" VERSION="7.3">XML file generated by PWSCF</creator>
    <created DATE="17Oct2024" TIME="14:54:36">This run was terminated on:  14:54:36  17 Oct 2024</created>
    <job></job>
  </general_info>
  <parallel_info>
    <nprocs>1</nprocs>
    <nthreads>1</nthreads>
    <ntasks>1</ntasks>
    <nbgrp>1</nbgrp>
    <npool>1</npool>
    <ndiag>1</ndiag>
  </parallel_info>
  <input>
    <control_variables>
      <title></title>
      <calculation>scf</calculation>
      <restart_mode>from_scratch</restart_mode>
      <prefix>NiO</prefix>
      <pseudo_dir>./pseudo/</pseudo_dir>
      <outdir>./</outdir>
      <stress>false</stress>
      <forces>false</forces>
      <wf_collect>true</wf_collect>
      <disk_io>low</disk_io>
      <max_seconds>36000</max_seconds>
      <nstep>1</nstep>
      <etot_conv_thr>5.000000000000000E-05</etot_conv_thr>
      <forc_conv_thr>5.000000000000000E-04</forc_conv_thr>
      <press_conv_thr>5.000000000000000E-01</press_conv_thr>
      <verbosity>low</verbosity>
      <print_every>100000</print_every>
      <fcp>false</fcp>
      <rism>false</rism>
    </control_variables>
    <atomic_species ntyp="3">
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 </partial>
    <partial label="sum_band:buf" calls="1430">
      <cpu>5.560761000003822E+00</cpu>
      <wall>2.205364704132080E-01</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="sum_band:ini" calls="1430">
      <cpu>1.645787500000188E+01</cpu>
      <wall>1.062707424163818E+00</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="sum_band:cal" calls="1430">
      <cpu>5.863581999994494E+00</cpu>
      <wall>2.234344482421875E-01</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="sum_band:bec" calls="1430">
      <cpu>1.747143000011874E+00</cpu>
      <wall>1.078259944915771E-01</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="addusdens" calls="11">
      <cpu>2.560491400000001E+01</cpu>
      <wall>1.703570842742920E+00</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="addusd:skk" calls="33">
      <cpu>8.189399999946545E-02</cpu>
      <wall>5.210399627685547E-03</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="sum_band:sym" calls="11">
      <cpu>4.394029999994018E-01</cpu>
      <wall>2.849674224853516E-02</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="mix_rho" calls="11">
      <cpu>9.877519999995457E-01</cpu>
      <wall>6.480765342712402E-02</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="high_freq_mi" calls="10">
      <cpu>2.465779999997721E-01</cpu>
      <wall>1.611781120300293E-02</wall>
    </partial>
    <partial label="ions" calls="1">
      <cpu>2.599999970698263E-05</cpu>
      <wall>1.907348632812500E-06</wall>
    </partial>
  </timing_info>
  <closed DATE="17 Oct 2024" TIME="14:54:36"></closed>
</qes:espresso>
                                                                  3454,1        Bot

End of Table 6A. Partial Listing of data-file-schema.xml
End of APPENDIX

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you find a solution? I have the same problem running QE on a supercomputer, any help will be much appreciated!
